# Node.js: Extracting the image urls of a webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get the images of a given webpage. I've tried using the modules `request` and `jsdom` as follows:

```
var request = require('request'),
    jsdom = require('jsdom');

request({ uri:'http://www.google.com' }, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error && response.statusCode !== 200) {
    console.log('Error when contacting google.com')
  }

  jsdom.env({
    html: body,
    scripts: [
      'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js'
    ]
  }, function (err, window) {
    var $ = window.jQuery;

    $(function () {
      console.log($('img').length);
    })
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, `console.log($('img').length);` prints `0` despite the page `google.com` containing images...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where does it contain `img` elements? I only see a `div` with background images. And for animated doodles it's usually a canvas.

Comment: Hum. I definitely have https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png

Comment: Interesting, was pretty sure that some time ago that was a background-image as well. Right now it displays an animated doodle with 2 divs for me.

Comment: @Randomblue can you get with jQuery any other element eg. div ? Maybe your browser gets version with image, but nodeJs gets other version (in my case i see div with background)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) jquery implementation in server.

Here is the Coffee script Gist to read image URL from the site

https://gist.github.com/mrjjwright/3240020

Javascript version

https://gist.github.com/fizerkhan/5633503